# Subscribe to array changes

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to use RxJS in an existing project that uses jQuery. Every time the button is clicked a new value is pushed to `users`. How do I see changes to `users` in `of(users).subscribe(...)`?

```
<button class="hello">Hello</button>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

const { of } = rxjs

let users = [
  { a: "b" }
]

of(users).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data)
})

jQuery(document).on('click', '.hello', function () {
  users.push({ c: 'd' })
})
```

Comment: An observable can use an array as input, but it can't 'listen' to it like this. Create an observable that listens to the button clicks - that's one of the primary use cases for observables

Comment: `of(users)` doesn't watch for changes to the array, it just gives you a single value stream of the current state of the array.

Comment: you may want to look into the 'fromEvent' rxjs operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the RxJS `scan` operator, you can transform a stream into a different form, similar to how JavaScript's native `.reduce()` method works. In this example, whenever you wanted to "push" to the users array, you could simply emit another user on the newUser subject.

```
// Create a new subject
const newUser = new Subject();

// Use scan to add new users into array of users
const users = newUser.pipe(scan((acc, user) => [ ...acc, user ], []));

// Subscribe to the list of users and log
users.subscribe(data => console.log(data));

// Add new user to array on document click
jQuery(document).on('click', '.hello', () => users.next({ c: 'd' }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative you can make use of the new ES6 proxy class together with Subject 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set

```
let usersUpdate=new Subject()
let users = [
  { a: "b" }
]

usersUpdate.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data)
})

let users=new Proxy([{ a: "b" }],{
set:(obj, prop, newval)=>{
    obj[prop] = newval
    userUpdate.next({obj, prop, newval})
    return true
   }
})

users.push('item')
```

Answer (score 1):

**One way would be to use `BehaviorSubject`**

So for your case would be to write following:

```
const users$ = new BehaviorSubject([{ a: 'b' }]);

users$.subscribe((users) => {
  console.log(users);
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.hello', function() {
  const users = [...users$.value]; // write like this so that array stays immutable
  users.push({ a: 'd' });
  users$.next(users);
});
```

Using `BehaviorSubject` gives you possibility to obtain **current value: `users$.value`**.

After `users$.next(users)` event will be emitted and `console.log(users)` will happen inside subscribe